# Mapping a list of dictionaries onto a pandas dataframe, matching on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my dataframe:

```
a  b       c     d
1  X  yellow  None
1  Y  yellow  None
1  Z    blue  None
```

Here is my incoming data:

```py
data = [
    {'a': 1, 'b': "X", 'c': 'red', 'd': True},
    {'a': 1, 'b': "Z", 'c': 'purple', 'd': False},
]
```

I would like to map the data onto the dataframe, updating columns 'c' and 'd' where columns 'a' and 'b' match the data.

The final result would look like this:

```
a  b       c     d
1  X     red  True
1  Y  yellow  None
1  Z  purple False
```

What is the most performant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `combine_first()`

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

df2.set_index(['a','b']).combine_first(df.set_index(['a','b'])).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   a  b       c      d
0  1  X     red   True
1  1  Y  yellow   None
2  1  Z  purple  False
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
pd.DataFrame(data).set_index(['a','b'])\
  .combine_first(df.set_index(['a', 'b']))\
  .reset_index().reindex_like(df)

   a  b       c      d
0  1  X     red   True
1  1  Y  yellow   None
2  1  Z  purple  False
```

Comment: The call to reindex_like is a useful addition. Not necessary in my case but good to keep in mind in case there is a need to preserve the original index

Answer (score 0):

I would probably concatenate your columns of interest into a single "composite key" column and then use that to map. I'm sure there's other fancy ways of doing it but keeping it simple might be best.